# Forecasting at different growth rate intervals

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, macroeconomics

I have a logged time series in monthly levels, e.g. an inflation index. Inflation is usually reported as a year-on-year (YoY) growth rate, that is: 
$$
YoY_t=\log(inflation)_{t}-\log(inflation)_{t-12}.
$$
For forecasting purposes, I use a given ARIMA specification. Should I forecast this YoY growth rate or rather start with the raw inflation index and forecast the month-on-month growth (MoM) rate? The latter is equivalent to the once differentiated time series:
$$
MoM_t=\log(inflation)_{t}-\log(inflation)_{t-1}.
$$

For now, lets assume the MoM series is seasonally adjusted (YoY takes care of this automatically...).

Somehow, I can only assume the autoregressive structure of YoY must be different to that of an MoM time series. On the one hand, I feel MoM is "cleaner" - more likely to be free of autoregressive components. The result can then be transformed in YoY. On the other hand, when directly using YoY, ARIMA optimizes directly on the YoY forecasting performance.

Any thoughts?